# PHP how to include a pie-chart

Tags: php, charts, visualization

I am working on a report and it is very static. I was asked to change some of the numbers into a pie-chart or cool graph. So been looking at canvasjs but cannot figure it out.

The code I work with simple

```
<tr><td><?php echo __( 'Average Pagespeed', 'mainwp-pro-reports-extension' ); ?></td><td>[pagespeed.average.desktop] / 100</td></tr>
                            [/remove-if-empty]
```

The output is very basic

Average Pagespeed 39 / 100

I want to learn how to transform this into a pie-chart and spice it up a little. If just know how it fits together, I can figure this out for the other values I think.

Can someone guide me?

This is my attempt : I am new to coding as you can see

```
<tr><td><?php echo __( 'Average Pagespeed', 'mainwp-pro-reports-extension' ); ?></td><td>[pagespeed.average.desktop] / 100</td></tr>

                                    <?php
                                    $dataPoints = array( 
                                        array("label"=>"Speed", "y"=>[pagespeed.average.desktop]),
                                        array("label"=>"Optimal", "y"=>100),
                                        )

                                    ?>
                                    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
                                    <html>
                                    <head>
                                    <script>
                                    window.onload = function() {


                                    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                                        animationEnabled: true,
                                        title: {
                                            text: "Page Speed"
                                        },
                                        subtitles: [{
                                            text: "November 2017"
                                        }],
                                        data: [{
                                            type: "pie",
                                            yValueFormatString: "#,##0.00\"%\"",
                                            indexLabel: "{label} ({y})",
                                            dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
                                        }]
                                    });
                                    chart.render();

                                    }
                                    </script>
                                    </head>
                                    <body>
                                    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
                                    <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
                            [/remove-if-empty]
```